# Difference Between range.Address & Range.Address(,,xlR1c1)

Tags: vba, excel

Find it strange, but there is a difference between output of first row & output of second row. Note the rows 641 & 641 are missed out in R1C1 format.

Any clue?

PS: Manually added spaces for readability purpose.

```
Debug.Print rngVisibleRange.Address
```

> $A$1:$XEW$1,   $A$226:$XEW$226,    $A$239:$XEW$239,    $A$370:$XEW$370,    $A$373:$XEW$374,    $A$462:$XEW$462,    $A$474:$XEW$474,    $A$479:$XEW$481,    $A$491:$XEW$491,    $A$523:$XEW$524,    $A$560:$XEW$560,    $A$582:$XEW$584,    $A$590:$XEW$591,    $A$637:$XEW$639,    $A$641:$XEW$643,    $A$648:$XEW$648

```
Debug.Print rngVisibleRange.Address(, , xlR1C1)
```

> R1C1:R1C16377, R226C1:R226C16377,  R239C1:R239C16377,  R370C1:R370C16377,  R373C1:R374C16377,  R462C1:R462C16377,  R474C1:R474C16377,  R479C1:R481C16377,  R491C1:R491C16377,  R523C1:R524C16377,  R560C1:R560C16377,  R582C1:R584C16377,  R590C1:R591C16377,  R637C1:R639C16377

**Verifiable example:**

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = [A1:XEW1,A226:XEW226,A239:XEW239,A370:XEW370,A373:XEW374,A462:XEW462,A474:XEW474,A479:XEW481,A491:XEW491,A523:XEW524,A560:XEW560,A582:XEW584,A590:XEW591,A637:XEW639,A641:XEW643,A648:XEW648]
    Debug.Print r.Areas.Count                              ' 16
    Debug.Print UBound(Split(r.Address, ","))              ' 15
    Debug.Print UBound(Split(r.Address(0, 0), ","))        ' 15
    Debug.Print UBound(Split(r.Address(, , xlR1C1), ","))  ' 13 (2 areas missing)
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you are passing the maximum length of `String` of 255 ? Try a shorter range, or remove the first 4 ranges from the one above and see if it displays it correctly

Comment: @ShaiRado, I am just printing them in Console using debug.print... Shouldn't have this issue.

Comment: @avdheshmaurya I hope you don't mind. I just added a small verifiable example to your post for everybody to reproduce the problem.

Comment: the result of `.Address` is limited to 255 characters, but I can't find any good reference source. You can loop the `range.Areas` to concatenate their adresses

Comment: @Ralph, appreciate that!

Comment: @ralph added `$A$648:$XEW$648` to the minimal example because it was missing and added the first debug.print line

Comment: @Slai While it seems that you are right this limit is not mentioned in the MSDN reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174749(v=office.11).aspx Instead you can read there that it returns a *string* (and we all know that strings in VBA can contain up to [2 ^ 31](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwcx436.aspx) Unicode characters.

Comment: @Ralph I had the same issue in .NET Interop.Excel so to me it seems more like a limit of `.Address`

Comment: @Slai it **is** a limit of `.Address` do a `Debug.Print len(rngVisibleRange.Address)` and you see that is more than 255.

Comment: the column 16377 is just few columns away from the last column, so if you  can use the whole rows, this would work `rngVisibleRange.EntireRow.Address(, , xlR1C1)`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the 255-character limitation the following two functions can be of help:

```
Public Function SetRange(s As String) As Range

Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(Split(s, ",")) To UBound(Split(s, ","))
    If SetRange Is Nothing Then
        Set SetRange = Worksheets(1).Range(Split(s, ",")(i))
    Else
        Set SetRange = Union(SetRange, Range(Split(s, ",")(i)))
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

---

```
Public Function GetRangeAddress(r As Range) As String

Dim i As Range

For Each i In r.Areas
    GetRangeAddress = GetRangeAddress & "," & i.Address(, , xlR1C1)
Next i

GetRangeAddress = Mid(GetRangeAddress, 2)

End Function
```

---

And here is a short `sub` that the two functions do their job:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub tmpSO()

Dim r As Range, s As String

s = "$A$1:$XEW$1, $A$226:$XEW$226, $A$239:$XEW$239, $A$370:$XEW$370, $A$373:$XEW$374, $A$462:$XEW$462, $A$474:$XEW$474, $A$479:$XEW$481, $A$491:$XEW$491, $A$523:$XEW$524, $A$560:$XEW$560, $A$582:$XEW$584, $A$590:$XEW$591, $A$637:$XEW$639, $A$641:$XEW$643, $A$648:$XEW$648"

Set r = SetRange(s)

Debug.Print r.Address
Debug.Print r.Address(, , xlR1C1)
Debug.Print GetRangeAddress(r)

End Sub
```

Note, that there is verification in these function which ensures that the string passed to `SetRange` can be actually used to point to a range. Also, the `SetRange` function automatically assumes `Worksheet(1)` in any given Excel file. Of course, this can be easily adjusted and both functions could be much improved: optional parameters such as *which worksheet to use for SetRange* or whether `GetRangeAddress` should return the address in *xlR1C1* style or not etc.

Yet, I wanted to keep it simple and just addressed the original problem.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, solves my issues to some extent. I am using another function to set the range hence the first function can't be used directly without modification which I would avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be useful, but when the areas are in the same column, the address can be much shorter in intersect form. For example `A:B (1:1,3:4)` or `C1:C2 (R1,R3:R4)`

```
Dim r As Range, s As String
Set r = [A1:XEW1,A226:XEW226,A239:XEW239,A370:XEW370,A373:XEW374,A462:XEW462,A474:XEW474,A479:XEW481,A491:XEW491,A523:XEW524,A560:XEW560,A582:XEW584,A590:XEW591,A637:XEW639,A641:XEW643,A648:XEW648]

' A1 and R1C1 regular form
s = r.Address(0, 0)
Debug.Print Len(s); UBound(Split(s, ",")); s ' " 187  15 A1:XEW1,A226:XEW226,A239:XEW239,A370:XEW370,A373:XEW374,A462:XEW462,A474:XEW474,A479:XEW481,A491:XEW491,A523:XEW524,A560:XEW560,A582:XEW584,A590:XEW591,A637:XEW639,A641:XEW643,A648:XEW648"

s = r.Address(, , xlR1C1)
Debug.Print Len(s), UBound(Split(s, ",")), s ' " 247  13 R1C1:R1C16377,R226C1:R226C16377,R239C1:R239C16377,R370C1:R370C16377,R373C1:R374C16377,R462C1:R462C16377,R474C1:R474C16377,R479C1:R481C16377,R491C1:R491C16377,R523C1:R524C16377,R560C1:R560C16377,R582C1:R584C16377,R590C1:R591C16377,R637C1:R639C16377"

' A1 and R1C1 intersect form
s = r.Areas(1).EntireColumn.Address(0, 0) & " (" & r.EntireRow.Address(0, 0) & ")"
Debug.Print Len(s), UBound(Split(s, ",")), s ' " 131  15 A:XEW (1:1,226:226,239:239,370:370,373:374,462:462,474:474,479:481,491:491,523:524,560:560,582:584,590:591,637:639,641:643,648:648)"

' R1C1 intersect
s = r.Areas(1).EntireColumn.Address(, , xlR1C1) & " (" & r.EntireRow.Address(, , xlR1C1) & ")"
Debug.Print Len(s), UBound(Split(s, ",")), s ' " 124  15 C1:C16377 (R1,R226,R239,R370,R373:R374,R462,R474,R479:R481,R491,R523:R524,R560,R582:R584,R590:R591,R637:R639,R641:R643,R648)"
```

Comment: It's ok that you found a shorter address for a specific example. But I guess the range of `rngVisibleRange` can change in his code. And if so it possibly will fail again even with your 'shorter' code. Better to solve this for any `range.address` longer than 255 characters **now** than 3 days later.

Comment: Thanks for reply Slai, I have a new perspective to look at my issue..:)